# jquery ui Portlet : incorrect effect on hover ( ui-state-hover )

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Portlet from jquery ui [Sortable Demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets).
I am trying to define Hover on `ui-icon-minusthick` by adding `ui-state-hover` class.
But the results are unexpected.I was hoping to get a rectangle on hover as is ui buttons but instead it shows a rectangle with weird background.

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ugnFw/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>
        Links
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Data Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.portlet{margin:0 1em 1em 0}
.portlet-header{padding-bottom:4px;padding-left:.2em;margin:.3em}
.portlet-header .ui-icon{float:right;margin-right:10px}
.portlet-content{padding:.4em}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".portlet-header .ui-icon").hover(

function () {
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ugnFw/10/

**CSS ADDITION:**

.portlet-header a {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 2px;
    position:relative;
}

HTML:

```
<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ">
        <a href="#" class=" ui-corner-all" title="close">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>
        </a>
        Links
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Data Content</div>
</div>
```